# Explain Idle, Sleep, Stop and Standby modes of power consumption in a microcontroller with examples

Tags: microcontroller, low-power, microprocessor, cpu, peripheral

It is given in a website that "In Idle Mode, the CPU and Flash are stopped. The rest of the chip continues to operate in this mode. If you do not need to execute code, but are taking a sensor measurement with the A/D or communicating to a radio, Idle Mode should be used."

I am confused about how a microcontroller (STM32L475) continues to take sensor measurement even after the CPU and Flash are stopped. I think Reading data from a sensor is an instruction which the CPU needs to execute by fetching it from the memory which is FLASH. If CPU and FLASH stop, how does the rest of the chip or peripherals do their work in Idle Power Mode?

Comment: This is related to STM32 Microcontrollers

Comment: Which STM32? There is hundreds of them and they could have different power saving modes. Add it to the question, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "reading data from a sensor is an instruction which the CPU needs to execute".  But the sensor can do other work while the CPU is stopped.  For example, the ADC peripheral can do the conversion (i.e. sampling the analog signal and converting it to bits).

The ADC peripheral is powered with a different clock than the CPU.  The ADC clock is not stopped in Idle Mode so that the ADC can continue to work while the CPU clock is stopped.

When the ADC conversion is complete, the ADC peripheral will interrupt the CPU and wake it up.  Then the CPU can execute instructions to read the sample value from the ADC peripheral.

The different power levels such as Idle, Sleep, and Standby correspond to different sets of internal clocks which are enabled/disabled.  Consult the microcontroller's reference manual for details.

Comment: Will CPU send signal or any interrupt to power up ADC Peripheral before going to Idle state? How will the different clock know when to trigger the ADC peripheral?

Comment: Yes, the CPU executes instructions to setup the ADC peripheral and start the ADC conversion before idling.  The ADC conversion takes some amount of time during which the CPU may be waiting.  The CPU can be idled while waiting for the ADC to complete.  Once started, the ADC peripheral completes the conversion(s) on its own without the CPU.  When the conversion is complete, the ADC peripheral interrupts the CPU to wake it up.  Upon receiving the ADC interrupt, the CPU can read the sample value from the ADC.  Clocks are just clocks -- clocks don't "interrupt" or "know" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Idle, sleep or stop is a different names for similar processes in different MCU. Usually microcontrollers have a few oscillators, and one of them is main. Programm runs from main oscillators, some periferals,like ADC, UART, timers, etc run with another oscillators,mostly slower then main. Then process end, they wake up  MCU from that mode. It is all for power saving. Some microcontrollers may have a few different power saving  modes. Reading sensor in that mode may be performed by external interrupt, which wake up MCU, or for instance MCU may wake up periodically, using internal timer.

Comment: My understanding is that an instruction (like reading a sensor value or ADC) is fetched from the program memory (FLASH) by CPU using main oscillator. After signal is given to the sensor or ADC, CPU and FLASH will stop and come to idle mode. How do oscillators know when to wake up CPU?

Comment: Takes some time to ADC convert signal. Then process ends it makes interrupt signal, which wake up MCU core, main oscilator starts and programm continue to run. It may be interrupt programm or next instruction, depends on setting.

Comment: Main oscillator does not run in idle mode. But some internal timer, runs from low frequency secondary oscillator,  wake up the core and initiate sensor reading. Also sensor may have interrupt request signal to start reading process.